# How to hide rows based on current selected cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to hide rows based on current selected cell? I always need to hide 4 rows from the 5th row down based on the selected cell.

I tried to make the following code:

```
function hidelines() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveRange().getNumRows();
  ss.getActiveSheet().hideRows(10, 4);
};
```

But he's always hiding from line 10. Is there any way to be based on the cell that I'm selected? Ex: if I'm on line 19, hide the lines 23 to 26? See that detected that I'm on line 19, counted 5 lines down, and hid 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hideFourFromFifth() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  var row=cell.getRow();
  sh.hideRows(row + 5, 4);
}
```

This one might be more useful:

```
function hideRowsFromOffset(offset,rows) {
  var offset=offset || 4;//if you're on 19 this will hide 23 to 26
  var rows=rows || 4;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  var row=cell.getRow();
  sh.hideRows(row + offset, rows);
}
```